# Disadvantages of running more epochs on same learn rate?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, data-mining

I ran the following Perceptron function from sklearn or scikit module and the number of n_tera are 40 . Total number of misclassifications were **4 out of 45** test data.

```
sklearn_percep=Perceptron(n_iter=40,eta0=0.1,random_state=0)
```

Later I made n_iterat to be 100 but now the misclassifications increased to **16 out of 45**.

```
 sklearn_percep=Perceptron(n_iter=100,eta0=0.1,random_state=0)
```

Out of curiosity I ran again for n_itera=1000 now the misclassifications are **5 out of 45**

I am using Iris Data Set and 3 classifications are present.I know when learning rate is very low epochs have to be high so as to reach convergence , but how does really high epochs reduce the performance of the learning algorithms ?

My Data is a 0.3 and 0.7 split out of 150 data rows and single time split

Thank You for your time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, given enough epochs, a stable classifier should converge. Once it has found a local minimum for its cost function, it should stay there. However, there will definitely be noise while the classifier is learning.

It is often good practice to keep track of accuracy on your test-set as you train. You can plot this to see how quickly the algorithm is converging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can you give any more deep insight regarding this?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but:

Effectively, what you're generating with your perceptron is a classifier that does not generalize to your test set. At 100 epochs (or, honestly, probably 10 epochs even), a perceptron should converge and separate your training set pretty well. However, that classifier may not effectively describe the split of all the data.

There are a number of things you can do to combat this, including regularizing your perceptron. You can try to impose an L1 or L2 penalty and see if it improves. Other algorithms also might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

n_iter, is a hyper parameter for Perceptron algorithm. Depend to your classification problem, and your data, this hyper parameter(n_iter) must properly choose

One useful trick is tuning hyper parameter(n_iter) with various number of integers and evaluate the classification accuracy. Try look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html for details. This is a good function to search for best hyper parameter, depend to your data